# PHP - Convert string to unicode

Tags: php, unicode, converters

I'm working on it

```
$source = mb_convert_encoding('test', "unicode", "utf-8");
$source = unpack('C*', $source);
var_dump($source);
```

return:

```
array (size=8)
  1 => int 0
  2 => int 116
  3 => int 0
  4 => int 101
  5 => int 0
  6 => int 115
  7 => int 0
  8 => int 116
```

but i want this return:

```
array (size=8)
  1 => int 116
  2 => int 0
  3 => int 101
  4 => int 0
  5 => int 115
  6 => int 0
  7 => int 116
  8 => int 0
```

I want use this return in openssl function for encryption. just `$source` important to me, i write other code for debugging.

What can i do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Unicode" is not a real encoding; it's the name of the overarching standard and used as an alias for UTF-16BE mostly by Microsoft, and apparently PHP supports it for that reason. What you expect is UTF-16LE, so use that explicitly:

```
$source = mb_convert_encoding('test', 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');
```